# Regular expression in JavaScript to match wildcard

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate the user input using the regular expression in JavaScript. Valid input are **at least** two characters with `*` symbol. In other words valid format is

```
< '*' or nothing><at least two characters>< '*' or nothing>
```

So of the valid inputs are

```
Mu*
*pa
*pa*
```

And invalid inputs are

```
*e*
*e*t
*e*t*
pa**
```

I am trying following expression but not working.

```
^{\*}?[A-Za-z]{\*}?$
```

Comment: ... [Why do you think that regex is even close to right?](http://regex101.com/r/xD5cE6/1) - Hint: [here's the right one](http://regex101.com/r/xD5cE6/2)

Comment: Which characters are you willing to accept as valid for the "at least two characters"? Letters, numbers, any special characters different from `*`?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol - ^\*?[A-Za-z]{2,}\*?$ is not matching any of the inputs

Comment: @Abecee -Two characters can be A-Z or a-z

Comment: Is `Mu` a valid string? Do you *require* at least one `*`? Your `< '*' or nothing>` description suggests that both `*`s are optional, and you may have neither.

Comment: Do you actually want 2 consecutive letters in input with one asterisk?

Comment: I need at least two character in between asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not simply this?

`/^\*?[a-zA-Z]{2,}\*?$/`

http://regex101.com/r/gT3nY4/1

Answer (score 2):

The definition isn't clear, but let's assume that a valid string must have either an initial or final `*` character (i.e., a string with no `*` at all is invalid). Whether a final `*` is required depends on the presence or absence of an initial `*`. I suspect (though I haven't proven) that this means your set of valid strings cannot be described by a regular language.

Instead, your language can be described as the union of two regular langauges: one whose strings end (and optionally begin) with a `*` and one whose strings begin (and optionally end) with a `*`:

```
/^\*?\w{2,}\*$|^\*\w{2,}\*?$/
```

Here, we accept

- minimum two-letter strings with a required final `*` (and an optional leading `*`) or
- minimum two-letter strings with a required leading `*` (and an optional final `*`).

Answer (score 1):

Adjusted: `^\*?\w{2,}\*?$` should do the trick.
Ooops: Just noticed the "hint" in @NiettheDarkAbsol comment - which gives basically the same solution.
However, we might both be wrong as all the examples for valid sequences do have at least one asterisk. Which is not explicit in the 'formal' description, though…

Comment: (star)pa(star)(star) is not valid input.

Comment: `Mu*` is valid - but `pa*`is not?

Comment: pa** is not valid input.

Comment: Addressed that by adding the anchors.